# 3D scatterplot that updates with time: MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, 3d, scatter-plot

What I am trying to do is to take data that is a list of points (x,y,z), individual "cells" on a scatter (there are 9 distinct cells: c=1,...,9), and t=time, and from this create a scatter3 that continually updates as the positions change over time. Since t starts at 0 for each point on the scatter there should be 9 points on the scatter plot at all times. So far all I have written is this code below which turns the lists into a matrix and plots each point (regardless of c value) sequentially with pauses according to the current and last value of t.

```
x=['x axis points'];
y=['y axis points'];
z=['z axis points'];
c=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3....8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]; %cells
t=[0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,,,,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,4,6,9,10,12,14]; %time resetting at 0 for each cell

mat=cell2mat({[x;y;z;c;t]}); %Convert cells into a matrix

scatter3(mat(1,2),mat(1,3),mat(1,4),100);
axis tight;

for jj=1:numel(mat(5,:))  %loops through for length of 5th row
scatter3(mat(1,jj),mat(2,jj),...
    mat(3,jj),100);       %plots point at t(x,y,z) w/ no regard to c
drawnow
if(jj>1 && mat(5,jj-1)>0)
    pause(mat(5,jj)-mat(5,jj-1))  %waits for difference in last two times if not 0
else
    pause(1) %otherwise pause a second
end
end
```

The first thing I need to do is modify the loop so that each scatter point is plotted-for each c at time t plot its point at corresponding (x,y,z).

- algorithm help would be nice, I haven't used MATLAB in years and my algorithm skills are rusty: can this be done with a for loop, should I sort the matrix according to time then split based on c?

Next I need to figure out a way to update points as time passes

- is it worth it to try to calculate a 3D distance between each point and have it 'slide' towards its destination gradually or would this be very difficult in MATLAB? Also how would this work with boundaries if two points are simultaneously in two very different places? Does the figure just automatically scale in MATLAB?

Once I have an algorithm that displays all points fluidly enough I can turn it into a video using code from this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnkTSX5U_a4

If anyone has wisdom in animating data like this please share tips or helpful bits of code. I have some programming background but not in representing data like this at all so I'm finding the easy stuff is throwing me for loops, sorry if this post comes across very n00bish.

example data:

```
 x=[-213.135 -217.261 -220.636  -225.325 -227.763 -232.826 -236.389 -239.577 
-238.827 -242.39];
 y=[92.081  90.955  88.892  86.83   84.767  82.891  84.392  80.453  75.765  
 73.327];
 z=[60 70   70  80  90  90  90  90  90  100];
 c=[1 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1];
 t=[0 1.008566667   2.017133333 3.025716667 4.034283333 5.04285 6.051416667 
 7.059983333    8.068566667 9.077133333];
```

Comment: Please include example `x`,`y` and `z` data so that your existing code can be run, for better understanding your problem

Comment: @Wolfie I added the first 10 numbers from my data, c=1 for all indicating it's the same cell. For plotting multiple points at once just duplicate this data and change the c value to 2,3,4... and vary one of the x,y,z values so they aren't plotted over each other, the time intervals are the same for each one I just realized so the program can update every point at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I've posted code for two methods, the second builds on the first to give your desired result.

---

**Setup**

You initial issue is that your data is all in row vectors. Let's make `x`,`y` and `z` into matrices with a different `c` "trajectory" on each row, using `reshape`

```
x = reshape(x, [], 9); % Makes x a 9 row matrix, assuming number of elements divisible by 9
```

The other function which will make your timings easier to handle is `diff`. This is simply the difference between neighbouring points in a vector, use it to get `dt`:

```
dt = [1, diff(t)];  % The 1 is needed as numel(diff(t)) = numel(t) - 1
```

Now you can use these to initialise your data:

```
% x,y and z are 10*9=90 element matrices, representing 9 trajectories.
% For real data, don't use REPMAT, use actual matrix. If data is just a 
% 90 element row vector, use RESHAPE to split into 9 rows.
x = repmat([-213 -217 -220 -225 -227 -232 -236 -239 -238 -242], 9, 1);
y = repmat([92.1 91.0 88.9 86.8 84.8 82.9 84.4 80.5 75.8 73.3], 9, 1);
z = repmat([60 70 70 80 90 90 90 90 90 100], 9, 1);
t = [0 1.0085 2.0171 3.0257 4.0342 5.0428 6.0514 7.0599 8.0685 9.0771];
dt = [1, diff(t)];  dt(dt < 0) = 1;  % Initialise dt, setting negative values to 1.

n = size(x,2);
% Offset z by row number. This wouldn't be needed with actual data.
% c is the trajectory number (1 - 9)
c = repmat((1:9)', 1, n); 
z = z - 5*c;
% Get axes limits, so they can be kept constant for the animation
lims = [min(x(:)), max(x(:)), min(y(:)), max(y(:)), min(z(:)), max(z(:))];
```

**Plotting coarse animation** - run after "Setup" code

```
% Plot actual points
figure;
for jj = 1:n            % Loop through all points in rows
    clf;                % Clear figure and hold on for multiple plots
    for ii = 1:9        % Loop over trajectories (rows)
        hold on;
        plot3(x(ii,jj), y(ii,jj), z(ii,jj), 'o');   % Plots point at x(t), y(t), z(t) 
        drawnow;
        hold off; view(-37.5, 30) % Hold off and set default 3D viewpoint
        axis(lims); grid on;
    end
    pause(dt(jj))    
end
```

---

**Plotting a smooth animation with trace lines** - run after "Setup" code

You wanted to have the points "slide". The easiest way is to use `interp1` to interpolate the points for you, then just plot them as before. In this example, I also plot the "historic" data lines

```
pts = 100;                                % Number of points (more is smoother)
x = interp1(1:n, x', linspace(1,n,pts))'; % Make x,y,z,t into pts number of points
y = interp1(1:n, y', linspace(1,n,pts))';
z = interp1(1:n, z', linspace(1,n,pts))';
t = interp1(1:n, t, linspace(1,n,pts));
dt = max(1/pts, [1/pts, diff(t)]);        % Set dt as positive time diff

% Plot smooth version, with trajectory lines
% Set up colours matrix so that plots points / lines can be the same colour
clrs = [linspace(0.4,0.8,9)', linspace(0.6,0.1,9)', linspace(0,0.5,9)'];
figure;
for jj = 1:pts            % Loop through all points in rows
    clf;                % Clear figure and hold on for multiple plots
    for ii = 1:9        % Loop over trajectories (rows)
        hold on;
        plot3(x(ii,jj),   y(ii,jj),   z(ii,jj),   'o', 'color', clrs(ii,:)); % Plots point at x(t), y(t), z(t) 
        plot3(x(ii,1:jj), y(ii,1:jj), z(ii,1:jj), '-', 'color', clrs(ii,:)); % Plot lines from T = 0 to T = t
        drawnow;
        hold off; view(-37.5, 30) % Hold off and set default 3D viewpoint
        axis(lims); grid on;
    end
    pause(dt(jj))    
end
```

Result (last plot):

[image: plot]

---

**Axes Limits**

Above, I have fixed the axes limits so that they are constant throughout the animation, and fit all of the points. You can leave them automatic using

```
axis auto
```

But this will make your animation look very jumpy!

---

**Making a movie**

You might find this entry on the File Exchange useful, it demonstrates generating a gif/movie using `imwrite` and looks very simple. I have not tested this, see the "Examples" tab for info:

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21944-animated-gif

Comment: thanks! Haven't tested yet but a very detailed answer this will no doubt give me a lot to work with

Comment: No worries @Mike, let me know if you have further issues. Cheers